# Align absolute positioned image to bottom of fixed div

Tags: html, css

I have got a sidebar navigation where the brand logo should be fixed to the bottom of navigation.

When i try `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` the image is on the bottom of the page and not at the bottom of the div.

I know i can solve this problem by setting `position: relative` to the parent div but the navigation has to be fixed.

Hope somebody can help me with this.

```css
.logo-bottom {
  width: 75%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  min-height: 100vh;
  left: 2.5%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="products">
    <img src="logo.png" class="logo-bottom" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the minimal part of code you have to reproduce this.

Comment: Just add the wrapper kind of div around your image div and set it's position to relative.

Comment: @Salketer added some code

Comment: Your `.menu` is at least 100vh in height. That means the logo isn't getting placed at the bottom of the page, but instead at the bottom of `.menu`. Which is, in this case, the same place. Wrap your link/logo in another div with `position:relative;`.

Comment: But the `img` is at the bottom of the `.menu` div!?

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer and inner element. In my code I used a flexbox to display the menu and logo. Hope this helps.

```css
.nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 1em 0;
display: flex;
}
li.logo {
align-self: flex-end;
}
li:not([class="logo"]) {
padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="logo"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x50" alt=""></li>
      <li>Menu option 1</li>
      <li>Menu option 2</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all your existing code to largely remain the same, you can simply wrap the menu in a div container with position relative and then use your anchor tag to position the image, this way the entire logo image is clickable.

Example CSS below

```
a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo-bottom {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xfbfezqp/1/